# Editing and Viewing Registry Keys from Powershell

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, powershell

I am working on learning Powershell and have been trying to write a script that will automatically map my drives to specific network drives.  That's easy enough, but I also want certain names associated with them from Windows Explorer.  This can be done from the registry, but I can't figure out how to do it from Powershell.  I researched online and I can navigate the registry like a normal drive up to a certain point now, using gci and set-location/cd, but once I am to the last folder key, I can't see the DWORDs inside the key using gci anymore.  From regedit, I know there are a bunch of keys inside.  My path is HKCU:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\mountpoints2##ComputerName#DriveName

Comment: You confuse the term "key" with the value(s) and their associated data contained in the key. In powershell, the values are considered to be "properties" of the key. Subkeys of the key are "childitems". Keys are containers, values are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple; use the command get-itemProperty to see all the keys.  So, if you've followed the path as far as you've got in your question, the command to see everything associated is:

```
get-itemproperty .\
```

You can obviously also see this from higher in the directory structure, just add the path after the .\

To accomplish your task of renaming the drive labels so they show up in Windows explorer, use the following:

```
set-itemProperty . _LabelFromDesktopINI "insert new label here"
```